# Nested foreach loops leading to a DataReader problem

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I´m struggling to solve this problem:

I have 2 foreach loops in a Controller, like this:

```
foreach (var item in processes)
{
    teste++;
    testando++;

    if (teste == 1)
    {
        process = item;

        if (trocaProc)
        {
            actualProcess = process;
            trocaProc = false;
        }

        var processId = (from t in _context.Process
                         where (t.Id == process)
                         select t.Id).First();

        machines1 = GetMachines(processId);
    }
    else
    {
        order = item;
    }

    if (testando == 1)
    {
        machines2 = machines1;
    }

    if (((testando % 2) == 0) && (testando >= 4))
    {
        IEnumerable<int> machinesA = machines2;
        IEnumerable<int> machinesB = machines1;

        foreach (var machine1 in machinesA)
        {
            // here is where the error occurs...
            foreach (var machine2 in machinesB) 
            {
                double quality = GetQuality(actualProcess, machine1);
                FlowReturn flowrow = new FlowReturn(flowId, maxcode, actualProcess, machine1, process, machine2, quality);
                fluxos.Add(flowrow);
                flowId++;
            }
        }

        trocaProc = false;
        actualProcess = process;

        machines2 = machines1;
    }

    if (teste == 2)
    {
        teste = 0;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set MySqlCommand.CommandText when there is an open DataReader for this command; it must be closed first.

I left a comment where the error occurs.

I have another version of this code working just fine, with the same Startup and Program. But this one, just doesn't run.

I have no idea how to solve this since MySql doesn't support MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets).

I don't mind rewrite this in a LINQ syntax that solves this, but is just one of my problems involving this situation. I need to use this context in more than one method at the same time also.

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NordyContext": "server=localhost;userid=root;password=rootroot;database=nrdoficial;"
  }
}
```

**Startup:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<NordyContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NordyContext"), builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("Nordy")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

and **Program:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

I need to use a `DbContext` instance in classes methods too and I think that is the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Stand back a bit. Forget how your program works. Now read your question. You don't mention where your error occurs (I'm guessing it's in the.loops, but...). I'm also guessing that there is some database operation happening in those loops (since the error is clearly ADO.NET related). Otherwise, can you tell what you are talking about. Read up on how to ask a question and about a [mcve]

Comment: You might also define`MARS`. Not everyone has seen that as an acronym for Multiple Active Result Sets. I hadn't (but I did know about Multiple Active Result Sets)

Comment: I´m sorry, I was in front of the computer for 6 hours trying to solve this and didn´t make the question properly. Anyway, it occurs as soon as it gets into the second loop.

Comment: I´m surprised too about the database operation happening inside of those loops, but that´s it. The whole code is over there. I updated with your suggestions.

Comment: What does `GetMachines` do?  I'm guessing it returns an `IQueryable`?  In which case it looks like your nested loop could be iterating over the same query.  You might want to do a `ToList` before you do your loops to materialize the query into memory.

Comment: The GetMachines returns a IEnumerable<int>. I´ll make it return a List<int> to try then.

Comment: I can´t believe it worked @juharr. Tanhk You VERY MUCH for your time and effort. I just made everything a List<> instead of a IEnumerable<> and now it works just fine!!!

Comment: @RenatoAzevedoZoppei Welcome on StackOverflow ;-)